# Blender Cycles Hair Transparency Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency, hair

I'm new here, but I made an account just to ask this.

Lately I've been working with an imported XPS model, but I haven't finished putting the textures on in Cycles yet. However, the hair (eyelashes and front hair) that I have textured doesn't seem to have working transparency. The hair strand indicated below seems to be 'transparent', but I don't know where the solid light blue color is coming from in the render; if I mess around with the nodes for that hair it usually ends up either turning the rendered blue part black or turning the entire strand black.

Does anyone have a fix? It would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Selected hair that isn't rendering properly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scratching my head for a few days I found the problem. There's a whole duplicate hair mesh which isn't visible from the front while editing, but shows up during renders. I went behind the model and loaded the texture onto the duplicate and everything works fine. Even the lashes.